# How to store multiply check boxes in to database with PDO Connection

Tags: php

I have the following problem which I can't resolve in which I've tried everything and nothing is working. The problem is that I want to store multiply checkboxes values into database, into one column one record inside it. Here is the Form code which I am using:

```
<label for="newsletter1">PRIMARIA:</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="field021[]" value="1" /> 1
<input type="checkbox" name="field021[]" value="2" /> 2
<input type="checkbox" name="field021[]" value="3" /> 3
```

for the PHP I am using a class file with the following storring parameteres:

```
public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
if( isset( $data['field021'] ) ) $this->field021 = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['field021'] ) );


public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
//store the parameters
$this->__construct( $params );
}

public function register() {
$correct = false;
try {
$con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(field021) VALUES(:field021)";


$stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue( "field021", $this->field021, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute();
```

right now nothing is getting writen in the database in the cell field021 , what I want to do is, to be able to register there multiply checkboxes devided by comma. If anyone can help, it will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function __construct( $data = array() ) {

    if(isset($data['field021'])) {

      // wrong: $data['field021'] is an array, so don't stripslashes() / strip_tags()
      //$this->field021 = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['field021'] ) );

      $this->field021 = array();
      foreach ($data['field021'] AS $key => $value) {
          $this->field021[$key] = stripslashes(strip_tags($value));
      }

      //   STRING                        ARRAY
      //    |  |                          | |
      //    V  V                          V V
      $this->field021 = implode(', ', $this->field021);

    } // end if

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like that?

```
$this->field021_commaseparated = implode(', ', $this->field021);
```

1. assuming `$data` === `$_POST`!?
2. you should not `stripslashes() / strip_tags()` an array!

Comment: usually when I am using the code without array <input type="checkbox" name="field021" value="1" /> 1  it is putting in the database the last or the highest value selected box. once I am using 
name="field021"[] it is not putting anyhting.

Comment: Because you do it wrong ... currently you have an array, but don't treat it like that.

Comment: This is the function for $_POST  public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
     //store the parameters
     $this->__construct( $params );
}

Comment: +1, @JohnSiniger and additionally I would set a specified key for each array element/checkbox; instead of `name="field021[]"` use `name="field021[1]"` as the names for the checkboxes